# Draw a circle around an annotation in MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am trying to draw a circle around an annotation to show a radius that will be geofenced.

Above my ViewController, I have a protocol that handles the results from a user's search

```
protocol HandleMapSearch {
    func dropPinZoomIn (placemark:MKPlacemark)
    func setUpGeofencing (placemark:MKPlacemark)
    func addRadiusCircle(placemark: MKPlacemark)
}
```

Within the ViewController class, I have a var `range` that is set by a slider.
Within my viewDidLoad I have `mapView.delegate = self`
and within the ViewController class, I have my mapView delegate function that should help draw my circle

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if overlay is MKCircle {
        let circle = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        circle.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
        circle.lineWidth = 1
        return circle
    } else {
        return MKPolylineRenderer()
    }
}
```

And my addRadiusCircle method looks like this

```
func addRadiusCircle(placemark: MKPlacemark){
    let circle = MKCircle(center: (placemark.location!.coordinate), radius: CLLocationDistance(range))
    mapView.add(circle)
}
```

When I test my app and search for a location, I get an annotation at the location's coordinates, but there is no circle around it. Is there an issue with the way I am attempting to draw the circle? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The shown code looks good. Make sure the delegates are set and that the parameter for the MKCircle call (center coordinate and radius) have the intended values, e.g. use the debugger or log it to the console. Note that the radius should be set in meters (not km or miles) from the center point.

Comment: Stephan, I added a breakpoint on the line `let circle = MKCircle(center: (placemark.location!.coordinate), radius: CLLocationDistance(range))` but my program never got there. I added a breakpoint on the last line of the method before it, and it was reached, but the later breakpoint was not executed

Comment: So it seems that 'addRadiusCircle' is never called? That could be the problem. When and where do you call it?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I had the delegate for the protocol in another class, and I forgot to call the addRadiusCirlce function from within that delegate.